# If $p$ is a prime such that $p≡1\pmod 7$ then $p ≡1\pmod{14}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove or disprove the following:

1)  if $p$ is odd prime such that $p≡1\pmod 7$ then $p ≡1\pmod{14}$

2)  if $p$ is odd prime such that $p≡4 \pmod 7$ then $p ≡4\pmod{14}$

I think that both statement are true and have a similar proof

1) $p≡1\pmod 7$ so $p≡8\pmod 7$ then $7|p-8$ so $p-8= 7 k$ where $k$ is an integer so $p=8+7k$, so $p ≡1\pmod {14}$

It is that a correct proof? Thank you.

Comment: If you could **explain** why $k$ had to be an **even** integer then you'd be in business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1:** if $p\equiv1\pmod7$, then $p\equiv1\pmod{14}$ or $p\equiv8\pmod{14}$.

**Hint 2:** if $p\equiv4\pmod{14}$, then $p=4+14k=2(2+7k)$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

---

The following explanation of Hint 1 bears on the answer in the question.

Note that if $p\equiv1\pmod7$, then $p=1+7k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $k$ is even, then $k=2j$, for some $j\in\mathbb{Z}$, and
$$
\begin{align}
p
&=1+7k\\
&=1+7(2j)\\
&=1+14j
\end{align}
$$
Thus, we get $p\equiv1\pmod{14}$. If $k$ is odd, then $k=2j+1$, for some $j\in\mathbb{Z}$, and
$$
\begin{align}
p
&=1+7k\\
&=1+7(2j+1)\\
&=8+14j
\end{align}
$$
Thus, we get $p\equiv8\pmod{14}$.

Comment: Sorry I still do not understand your hint could you please explain more thank you

Comment: @dr.rise: if $p\equiv8\pmod{14}$, then $p=8+14k=2(4+7k)$, for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Right so let's look at some numbers such that $p \equiv 1 \mod{7}$, we have $1,8,15,...$. Now what are these numbers mod 14? They are $15 \equiv 1 \mod{14}$ and $8\equiv 8 \mod{14}$.

Comment: @Boots: "$15 \equiv 8 \equiv 1 \mod{14}$" doesn't look right. Can you explain what that means?

Comment: @robjohn Right, I made a small typo, I've fixed it. I'm showing an example of what you said, because he said he does not understand what you meant.

Comment: I edit my answer is it now ok? thanks

Comment: @robjohn , does what you said  above works with p is odd prime or there is difference in the answer? thank you very much

Comment: @dr.rise: I don't think there would be any difference. The only difference might be if we were looking at $p\equiv2\pmod7$.

Answer (score 1):

1) $p-1=7r;$  $p\not =2$, I.e.

$p$ is odd, $p-1$ is even.

Hence : $2| (p-1)$ ;

Euclid's Lemma:

$2|7r,$ then $2|r$. I.e $r=2s.$

Hence: $p-1 = 7×2s = 14 s.$

2) Can you handle it?

($p-4 =7r$, $p-4$ is even, why?)

Comment: thank you very much but the question does not said p is odd prime .

Comment: Dr.rise :  p=2 = 2 mod 7; all other primes are odd.Am I wrong?

Comment: YES, you are right p=2 is the only even prime and the other is odd prime

Comment: $p$ is odd, $p-1$ is even. but how about if p is 2 ?

Comment: But dr.rise: p=2, then 2 = 2mod 7, not p=1 mod 7 as in your problem . So p=2 need not be considered. You agree?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: if $p\equiv 1\bmod 7$ then it means that exists some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac{p}7=n+\frac17$, and if $p\equiv 1\bmod 14$ also then it means that there is some $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $$\frac{p}{14}=m+\frac1{14}=\frac{n}2+\frac1{14}=\frac12\cdot\frac{p}7$$

Hence you need to show that $n$ is even or, if the statement would not be true, that there is some odd $n$ for some prime $p$.

> If $p=7n+1$ is prime then necessarily $7n$ is even, because the unique even prime is $2$.

You can apply the same reasoning for the other case.

Answer (score 1):

Best bet for these statements is to try some examples to see if primes fall into these categories:

1.) Numbers of the form $p\equiv 1\pmod 7$ (Primes in bold): $1, 8, 15, 22, {\bf29}, 36, {\bf43},\dots$.

2.) Numbers of the form $p\equiv 4\pmod 7$ (Primes in bold): $4, {\bf 11}, 18, 25, 32, 39, 46, {\bf 53},\dots$.

Can you make some assumptions from here?