# if p is odd prime such that $p \equiv 1\,(\text{mod } 7)$ then $p \equiv 1\,(\text{mod } 14)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove :

if $p$ is odd prime such that $$p\equiv 1 \ (\bmod 7)$$ then $$p \equiv 1\ (\bmod 14)$$

my prove for it that let $p$ is odd prime and $p\equiv 1 \ (\bmod 7)$ so every odd prime number can be written as $p\equiv 1 \ (\bmod 2)$ so by multiple the  $p\equiv 1\ (\bmod 7)$  and  $p\equiv 1\ (\bmod 2)$

we get  $$p\equiv 1\ (\bmod 14)$$

is that right please?

Comment: @DonAntonio but the p is odd prime so we cannot choose 22

Comment: That is basically right.   We formally call it the https://en..wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559664/if-p-is-a-prime-such-that-p≡1-pmod-7-then-p-≡1-pmod14/2559670

Comment: @dr.rise Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the constant case of the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

You have two coprime moduli $p$ and $q$ and specify that another value $v$ has $v\equiv k \bmod p$ and $v \equiv k \bmod q$, which leads to $v=k \bmod pq$ by the Chinese Remainder theorem.

Here $p=7$, $q=2$ and $k=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$p\equiv 1\ (\bmod 14)\iff p\equiv 1\ (\bmod 2) \land p\equiv 1\ (\bmod 7) $$

thus

for

$$p\equiv 1\ (\bmod 2)$$

$$p\equiv 1\ (\bmod 7)\iff p\equiv 1\ (\bmod 14)$$